# css stylesheet not loading and response body is the html that tried to link it

Tags: php, html, css, apache, firefox

### Overall, my issue is that I cannot link my external css stylesheet.

- I have two external stylesheets with *identical* content: land.css and test.css.
- land.css links in fine, but test.css returns the html file (land.html.php) that tried to link it in the response body.

### Here are the details of the server response:

When I link test.css, the external stylesheet does not get returned properly, and the response body for test.css is land.html.php:
[faulty server response to test.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvGl2.png)

When I link land.css, the external stylesheet loads just fine, and the response body for land.css is land.css (as it should be):
[proper server response to land.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpvrw.png)

### I looked into the mime config to make sure all .css files would be served as content-type text/css. I have done the following troubleshooting..

1. I confirmed that /etc/mime.types includes the line `text/css css`
2. I confirmed that /etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf contains `TypesConfig /etc/mime.types`, and /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ symlinks mime.conf
3. I added `AddType text/css .css` to /etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf, /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, and my `<VirtualHost>`--overkill, but none of these seem to work
4. I restarted the apache2 service... no luck
5. I enabled the mod_headers module and added the following to my apache.conf file, but no luck still:
   `<FilesMatch *.css>
   Header set Content-Type "text/css"
   </FilesMatch>`

### Here are the details of the code:

All of these files reside in the same directory and apache serves them with return status 200
- land.html.php (line 1) :: `<?php include head.html.php ?>`
- head.html.php ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">

  <title>Welcome</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJ$
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="page-header"></div>

</head>
```

- test.css and land.css have **equivalent contents** shown here::

```
.navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ee343a 0%,#468be6 100%);
  padding:1% 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #bec6e0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a.active {
  color: #dfdfda;
}
#home {
  background: url(images/Bikeclouds.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 400px;
  opacity: .75;
}
.landing-text {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.landing-text h1 {
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.padding img {
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #23415c;
  padding: 5% 5% 10% 5%;
  color: #dce5f4;
}
.fa {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8f9d88
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJ$` just faulty in your Post here or did you forget to close it with `/>` in your code as well?

Comment: Also check if you are actually trying to debug client side cached results.

Comment: Can you please check in browser dev tools, what the actual response body for the test.css request looks like?

Comment: btw, since your faulty one has a Content-length of 1112 Characters, and your correct one has 447 Characters of content-length, are you sure that their content is "equivalent"?

Comment: @D.Schaller the link was cut off by stack overflow's text display. There is indeed a /> at the end of the line in my source code. Good catch! On the content-length disparity, this is related to misorude's note. The actual response body for test.css is land.html.php (1112 characters). The response body for land.css is land.css (447 characters) as it should be. This is certainly part of the problem. Thank you for your questions--further thoughts?

Comment: @arkascha I was careful to turn off caching and ensure that my .css was not cached every time I reloaded the page. Good thought--thank you for asking

Comment: @misorude you bring up another part of this issue that may be closer to root cause. The actual response body for test.css is land.html.php. The actual response body for land.css is land.css (as it should be). I found others who solved problems of failed css linking by ensuring Content-Type text/css, but perhaps my issue is different. Thank you for your question--I will edit my original question to highlight this aspect of the failed link.